# Which are the requirements for the water supply on board?

Tags: commercial-aviation

Which are the requirements for the water supply on board of a commercial airplane? I know that there are minumum mandatory requirements, but I don't know where to find them and how they can change with the category of the aircraft. Surely there are different requirements from a small turboprop without a toilet to a A320.

Comment: On board what? A private helicopter? A small prop plane? A huge passenger jet? A short domestic flight? A long intercontinental flight? A military fighter over enemy territory?

Comment: It looks like [it's complicated](https://www.epa.gov/dwreginfo/aircraft-drinking-water-rule), at least in the US: three different agencies are involved, and only one of them is aviation-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IATA standards as per the IATA Drinking Water Quality Pool are based on

> ISO 17775, WHO requirements or EU/98/83/EC or those set by the civil aviation authorities of the participating airlines

[Source](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/safety/audit/Pages/idqp.aspx)

Airlines and operators will periodically test their water in aircraft, ground service vehicles, and filling stations for bacteria contamination (E-coli, coliform, etc).

Some aircraft may not actually have potable water tanks or may have removed them. Horizon Air operates their Q400 Dash 8 aircraft without potable water.